# Javascript function assignment not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

The following code works in all major modern browsers (Chrome, FF, Safari and IE 11+) except IE10.

```
var a = console.log;
a('hello');
```

In IE10, it throws an error - 'Invalid calling object'.
I'm wondering if this is an IE10 specific issue/feature or the way I assign function to a variable is not encouraged in JS?

Comment: Is that the only function assignment like that which doesn't work in IE10?

Comment: My hunch is that this is limited to functions that call native code. Btw, what happens if you do `a.call(console, 'hello')`?

Comment: @Paraknight good call, that expression works fine in IE. As mentioned in a duplicate question, it might related to binding context when assigning function to a variable.